# Как связать массив объектов с элементами в ячейках Grid-а

Tags: wpf, xaml

Есть массив неких объектов в двумерном массиве, к примеру 5х5
Есть верстка в XAML состоящего из простого Grid тоже с пятью колонками и строками. В каждой ячейке расположен TextBox.
Как корректно связать объект двумерного массива с определенным TextBox в разметке?

Comment: А какого в точности типа ваш двумерный массив? Реально `string[,]`?

Comment: нет это экземпляры некоего класса типа MyObject[,]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ваша структура данных реально состоит из вложенных списков (например `List<List<T>>` или там на худой конец `T[][]`), вы можете использовать рекурсивно `ItemsControl`. (Если реально прямоугольный массив вида `T[,]`, смотрите в конце ответа.) Трюк только в том, что либо внутренний, либо внешний `ItemsControl` должен располагать элементы горизонтально.

С вот таким XAML'ом:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BVC"/>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <!-- здесь код представления вашего одного элемента -->
                        <Grid Width="50" Height="50" Background="Red">
                            <Grid Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BVC}}"
                                  Background="Green"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                       VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

и вот такой структурой данных в качестве `DataContext`:

```
bool[][] items = new []
{
    new[] { true, false, false, false,  true },
    new[] { true,  true, false, false, false },
    new[] { true, false,  true, false, false },
    new[] { true, false, false,  true, false },
    new[] { true,  true,  true,  true,  true }
};
```

вы получаете такое отображение:

[image: правда или ложь — и не разберёшь]

---

Если у вас и правда многомерный массив (`T[,]`), установите в качестве `DataContext` такой wrapper:

```
class TwoDimensionnalArrayWrapper<T> : IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>
{
    T[,] array;

    public TwoDimensionnalArrayWrapper(T[,] array)
    {
        this.array = array;
    }

    public IEnumerator<IEnumerable<T>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        var w = array.GetLength(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < w; i++)
            yield return ColumnWrapper(i);
    }

    IEnumerable<T> ColumnWrapper(int i)
    {
        var h = array.GetLength(1);
        for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
            yield return array[i, j];
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Сам уже стал задумываться об ItemsControl, только не мог понять, как его использовать, в данной ситуации. Оказывается - можно рекурсивно.

Comment: @Sublihim: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помогло.

Comment: Внезапно возник еще один вопрос к данному шаблону. Дело в том, что если в DataTemplate разместить, к примеру Image в который поместить картинку достаточно большого размера, то эта картинка так и отобразиться в своем реальном размере. Как, используя данный шаблон, можно сделать так, чтобы ItemsControl занимал размер пропорционально окну, и, соотвественно, картинки так же сжимались?

Comment: @Sublihim: Странно, картинка у меня не растягивается, если оставить у `Grid` атрибуты `Width="50" Height="50"`. По поводу того, как сделать поле растягивающимся, стоит задать отдельный вопрос, тут мало места, да и тема не вполне относится к данному вопросу.

Comment: Да, если выставить ограничение - то будут заданные размеры.

Comment: Но, хорошо, задам отдельный вопрос