# Автоподбор размера изображения в ItemsControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

По мотивам вопроса [Как связать массив объектов с элементами в ячейках Grid-а](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549154/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D1%81-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D1%8F%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%85-grid-%D0%B0)

В отличии от указанного в ссылке вопроса, у меня есть одномерный массив данных, который надо отобразить в строго заданное количество строк и столбцов (допустим 2 строки и 3 колонки).

Вот пример:

Есть класс, хранящий информацию об изображении:

```
class ImageInfo
{
    private string imgPath_;

    public Uri Uri
    {
        get { return new Uri(imgPath_, UriKind.Relative);}
    }

    public ImageInfo(string imgPath)
    {
        imgPath_ = imgPath;
    }
}
```

Есть массив этих классов:

```
ImageInfo[] imgInfo_ = new ImageInfo[]
    {
        new ImageInfo("img/0.jpg"),
        new ImageInfo("img/1.jpg"),
        new ImageInfo("img/2.jpg"),
        new ImageInfo("img/3.jpg"),
        new ImageInfo("img/4.jpg"),
        new ImageInfo("img/5.jpg")  
    };
```

Есть конвертер линейного массива в двумерный:

```
class ImgProvider : IEnumerable<IEnumerable<ImageInfo>>
{
    readonly int ROW_COUNT = 2;
    readonly int COL_COUNT = 3;

    List<ImageInfo> _imgInfo;

    public ImgProvider(List<ImageInfo> imgInfo)
    {
        _imgInfo = imgInfo;
    }

    public IEnumerator<IEnumerable<ImageInfo>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ROW_COUNT; i++)
        {
            yield return ColumnWraper(i);
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<ImageInfo> ColumnWraper(int i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL_COUNT; j++)
        {
            int num = i == 0 ? j : j + COL_COUNT;
            yield return _imgInfo[num];
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => GetEnumerator();
}
```

Разметка, отображающая 2 ряда изображений, используя рекурсивный `ItemsControl`:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="IC" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Orientation="Horizontal"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>                        
                        <Grid>
                           <Button>
                              <Button.Template>
                                 <ControlTemplate>
                                   <Image Source="{Binding Path=Uri}"/>
                                 </ControlTemplate>
                              </Button.Template>
                           </Button>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Устанавливаю `DataContext`:

```
IC.DataContext = new ImgProvider(imgInfo.ToList<ImageInfo>());
```

Если задать размер `Width` и `Height`(к примеру 100х100) у `Grid`-а, в который вложен `Button` с картинкой, то получаем форму следующего вида:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

т.е. все картинки естественно помещаются

Но если убрать размер у `Grid`-а то картинки растянутся до своего истинного размера:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос**: как сделать так, чтобы картинки равномерно растягивались во всю форму? Т.е. помещались бы все 2 ряда и при изменении размера формы, изменялся бы и размер картинок?

**UPD:** Если использовать `UniformGrid Columns="3"`, вместо `StackPanel`, как рекомендовано в приведенном ответе, то ситуация становится лучше, но все-равно картинки не умещаются целиком:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если посмотреть в Live Tree View, то увидим следующую ситуацию:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В `ItemsPresenter` вложена `StackPanel`, которая, видимо и растягивается под контент

Comment: А можно выложить улиточку в виде картинки для экспериментов?

Comment: @VladD, без проблем - вот [ссылка на улиточку](https://yadi.sk/i/C80hPn4r34mVny)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы используете StackPanel для выведения элементов, она не умеет подстраивать размер дочерних объектов под доступный. Для решения этой задачи лучше всего заменить двумерный массив и вложенный ItemsControl (вместе, конечно же, с данными, привязываемыми через DataContext — скажем, заменив `ImgProvider` на `_imgInfo`) на обычный список, использующий UniformGrid с `Columns="3"` (или `Rows="2"`). Ну или, если нужно оставить именно двумерный массив, просто замените StackPanel на ItemsControl с `Rows="1"`, например.

Один из вариантов решения:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="IC" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid IsItemsHost="True" Columns="3" Rows="2" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button>
              <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                   <Image Source="{Binding Path=Uri}"/>
                 </ControlTemplate>
               </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: У меня ситуация такая, есть одномерные данные, содержащие картинки, которые надо вывести в два ряда. Поэтому я и использую такой "финт ушами" - провайдер, который бинжу к такому `ItemsControl`. Не могли бы вы к вашему ответу добавить пример на `xaml` чтобы было понятней, что вы имеете ввиду.

Comment: @Sublihim, добавил пример.

Comment: спасибо за пример. попробовал. Ситуация стала лучше, чем со `StackPanel` но, картинки все-равно не умещаются в размер. Сейчас добавлю скриншот в основной вопрос.

Comment: @Sublihim, а как ItemsControl выводится? Случайно не в StackPanel (которая, в свою очередь, в Window)?

Comment: нет, идет Window, пустой Grid, а в нем ItemsControl

Comment: Даже если выбрасываю промежуточный Grid и помещаю ItemsControl в Window, ситуация не улучшается

Comment: @Sublihim, а если заменить «Columns="3"» на «Rows="2"»?

Comment: нет, так еще хуже выходит

Comment: Ситуация такая. Я наконец увидел, что моя схема `xaml`, немного отличается, от приведенной вами в ответе. И скриншоты, которые я приводил, тоже основаны на моей схеме. Если посмотреть Live Tree View, когда я использую UniformGrid, то там все-равно присутствует StackPanel, в которой содержатся оба ContentPresenter-а, которые соответствуют строкам. Если использовать конкретно ваш `xaml` приведенный в ответе, то StackPanel-и там нет, но изображения и с rows=2 и columns=3 все-равно не помещаются в window

Comment: @Sublihim: У меня с кодом из ответа получается вот что: http://imgur.com/Q9fW6dH. Разве это не то, что надо? Я только поставил `<UniformGrid IsItemsHost="True" Rows="2" Columns="3"/>`.

Comment: @VladD хм. это именно то, что надо. Но почему-то у меня, полностью скопипастив код из примера, получается фигня http://imgur.com/ojOIxTI

Comment: @Sublihim: При этом DataContext — просто `imgInfo_`, без промежуточного `ImgProvider`

Comment: @Sublihim: Сейчас выложу весь код

Comment: @VladD, действительно получилось!

Comment: @Sublihim: MainWindow.xaml: http://pastebin.com/QXW7Q2tP MainWindow.xaml.cs: http://pastebin.com/zCR7gKm6

Comment: @Sublihim: Отлично, тогда этот ответ правильный. :)

Comment: @VladD, спасибо :)

Comment: @Sublihim: Пожалуйста!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50667/discussion-between-sublihim-and-vladd).